# java: Is there a way to determine if a given String represents an absolute path on another OS?

Tags: java, string, file, path

If I have String s and wish to determine whether it represents an absolute path on the local file system, I can do it via:

```
new File(s).isAbsolute()
```

But how to do this for something other than the local operating system - e.g. if I'm on a Mac and want to check whether s represents an absolute path on MS Windows?

Comment: I assume you don’t care if the path actually exists or not. Just that it is absolute.

Comment: The support from the underlying operating system is not available on other platforms.  The safe answer is:  Code it yourself.

Comment: Do you know the type of the other OS?  Your example suggests the other is Windows, but in practice, will the remote OS type been a known or unknown?

Comment: Correct - I don't care if it's actually an existing file.  Yes, I do know the type of the other OS - it's either Windows or Linux.